# Naming specifc shapes using VBA

Tags: vba

I have a presentation deck in PowerPoint with many shapes. Is there a way to name all shapes that are graphs (linked from Excel workbook) only. For example one slide has 4 graphs, so the name of the shapes are MyPicture1,  MyPicture2, MyPicture3 and MyPicture4. The code so far looks like

```
Sub test()
Dim lctr As Long
Dim shp As shape
Dim ii As Integer

For ii = 1 To 6
    For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(ii).Shapes
        If shp.Type = msoChart Then
        lctr = lctr + 1
        shp.Name = "MyPicture" & lctr
    End If
    Next shp
Next ii
```

Comment: as far as I know the object in PowerPoint don't have names. You can get their Shape Index in the slide.

Comment: You can name your shapes in Picture Tools -> Selection Pane

Comment: what PowerPoint version ? I couldn't find this toolbar, where is it located ?

Comment: What does your code do so far or what kind of error is thrown?

Comment: PowerPoint 2010. No errors from the program. The condition 'If shp.Type = msoChart Then' is never fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to list names of all **charts** in your presentation. To do so, you can use a single loop like:

```
Dim shp as Shape
For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes
 If shp.Type = msoChart Then
  Debug.Print shp.Name
 End If
Next
```

Edit: Or you can also use `Shape.HasChart` property.

```
If shp.HasChart Then
 Debug.Print shp.Name
End If
```

Comment: I need to dim Chart. What is the dim?

Comment: Dim Chart as Shape

Comment: I had to do some changes to fit to my purpose and it don't re-name my charts. I have amended my question with my code.